# Laravel - Search through table by name & pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-5

I'm making an admin panel and on my users page, I have a table with 53 users. (without pagination). On top of that table, I have an input field which is supposed to act as a search bar. But I don't know how to make it. I want the user to search a username and then the results immediately pop-up without a refresh. So the search needs to be searching by first name.

Are there any good tutorials for this that can help me on my way?

Also, The table has 53 users. How can I paginate the table to show only 25 per page? Because my table currently looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1voZ8.jpg. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The number of the users will be always that small (53 users)?

Comment: No, everytime a user registers it goes +1. It's dynamic. And then the user gets added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTables for that. It is a jQuery plugin that allows you to implement a search bar and the results will be shown immediately. It also implements pagination dinamically.

Ref: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

The code is very simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

It also has several additional configuration.

But, if you need to use it in a huge table, with a lot of results, it is not a good option, because it will take a lot of time to load.

Comment: I rather have my own designs with search and pagination. Do you have another solution\?

Comment: Actually, you can apply your own CSS to DataTables. But, if you want to customize everything, I don't know any plugin for that. But you can make it with Ajax for searching, rendering a Blade template in Controller and send it as the result. So, when you get the result in Ajax call, you can just set HTML code to a reference div.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't change table than you can use this
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination

or

if you can can change table than it's give best pagination or search functionality in laravel

https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagination with search like this.

```
    $search    = strtolower($request->input('search'));
    if ($search != '') {
        $users = $user->where('name', 'like', "%$search%")
                      ->orWhere('email', 'like', "%$search%")
                      ->paginate(10);
    } else {
        $users = $user->paginate(10);
    }
```